# How to change the screen resolution when using RDesktop?

Tags: display-resolution, remote-desktop, rdesktop

How to change the screen resolution?

I tried with this command:

```
rdesktop <server_ip>
```

But the screen does not appear large.

Comment: FYI, using the -f option will use ALL the connected monitors...

Answer (score 70):

I like using this command:

```
rdesktop -g 90% servername
```

Which will set the size of the remote desktop to 90% of the size of your local screen, which works quite well regardless of resolution.

Comment: Problems if you have a dual-screen...

Comment: Is there viable solutions from WindowsNT to Gnome that offer specifying graphical resolution?

Comment: **For dual screen**: `-g $(xrandr -q | awk '/Screen 0/ {print int($8/1.28) $9 int($10/1.2)}' | sed 's/,//g')`

Comment: Sorry, old thread.  But when I work on a multiple monitor workstation I like that the remote desktop only in on one screen. I modified gacenkoa awesome script to this: `-g $(xrandr -q | awk '/ connected / {print $4;exit}' | awk -F "x" '{print int($1/1.05)"x"int($2/1.1)}')` This will look for the first connected monitor and then make the window a little smaller than that screen.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to open the screen at a specific resolution, for example `1280×1024` resolution, add the `-g` flag:

```
rdesktop -g 1280x1024 <server_ip>
```

Comment: Somehow I can make it as wide as I want, but the height is very limited.

Answer (score 15):

This command gives you a full screen experience as well:

```
rdesktop -f
```

Comment: Doesn't work well with multiple displays: it spreads the window over all of them.

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + Enter` if you're wondering how to minimise / exit the remote session

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer to my question.

- `-k de`: set keyboard layout
- `-g 1500x1150`: set resolution of the rdesktop window
- `-r disk:mydisk=/home/soma`: share your home directory with the remote machine

The full command should be:

```
rdesktop 192.168.1.23 -k de -g 1500x1150 -r disk:mydisk=/home/soma
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest that you consider a graphical tool such as [Remmina (used to be called GRDC)](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/), which is available in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc
```

It features easy to use drop downs and sliders for remote screen resolution, supporting multiple monitors and more.

It also supports VNC and SSH tunnelling, making it a one-stop-shop for all your most likely remote desktop connection needs.  Finally, a handy gnome-panel applet makes connecting to your remote desktops a simple point and click experience.

Screenshots here : http://remmina.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml

Comment: remmina-gnome doesn't exist (at least in Oneiric), but this worked for me: sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc

Comment: Nice one - they must have updated the packages in Oneiric.  Have updated my answer.

Comment: And upvoted you for the call out!

Comment: But remmina does not work properly with 3G. You have to connect 20 times until yo

Answer (score 4):

I had the problem on my Ubuntu 20.10 notebook that my screen has 1920x1080 but only 14 inch, so the dpi is higher on my notebook screen than on the monitor of the remote computer

I could adjust this by using `-g` parameter with the DPI option, that is specified via an `@` sign.

```
rdesktop -g 100%@150 <remote_computer>
```

The `100%` refer to my screen size and the higher the value after the 1

Comment: thanks (from 2021).

Answer (score 3):

Use the @DPI scaling option. Valid range is from 96 to 480 on Windows.
Try @144 for 150% scaling, or @192 for 200% scaling.

For example:

```
rdesktop -g 90%@192 <server>
```

or

```
rdesktop -g 3000x1660@150 <server>
```

From the rdesktop man page:

> -g <geometry>
>
> Desktop geometry (WxH[@DPI][+X[+Y]]) ...
> The  optional  DPI parameter should be specified if the screen
> rdesktop is being displayed on is too far from 96 DPI for unscaled
> Windows to be readable. Windows  currently accepts values from 96 to
> 480.

Answer (score -1):

oldSkool:

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>KP+</kbd>  also cycles through some available resolutions.

Comment: That's for the local display resolution.  He's using `rdesktop` which used RDP to pull a display from a remote Windows system.  It's the resolution of thew Windows system displayed on his workstation he wants to adjust.

Comment: what's `KP+` ? -- probably  the Plus on the numeric KeyPad